# Windows login with MFC application

Tags: windows, mfc, authentication

I'm developing a face recognition login application in MFC.
How can I run my application when the windows login screen appears and how can I login (having the username and password) if face is recognized?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you implementing the facial recognition algorithm?

Comment: I've implemented it in OpenCV.

Comment: are you going to open source the project?  I've never had a look at a facial recognition system and I am curious.  I spend most of my time on DirectShow apps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a [windows credential provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Vista and later only, so only useful if your users can abandon XP...

If they can't, your only option is [customizing the windows login with Gina](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. Not only do I forget all the time how that thing which replaced GINA was named, but the article actually sheds light on the history, too :)

Comment: Hi, i have tested the windows credential provider sample application but nothing is happening. I've build the app, copied the dll file, ran the Register.reg file and the Administrator and Guest accounts didn't appeared on restart or switch user. I checked the registers and the dll are there. What i did wrong? I followed the "Windows Vista Credential Provider Samples Overview" document steps. Thank you. (i'm using Windows 7 professional)